# How to change the Wordpress role assigned through "Create User Record" function

Tags: wordpress, contacts, user, roles

When using the "Create User Record" function on a CiviCRM Contact record, a wordpress (or other CMS) user is created.

How can the default wordpress/CMS role of that user be modified in CiviCRM? By default it seems to be "Subscriber".
Is it possible to add other roles (in CiviCRM or in the CMS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be hardcoded to the default role: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/79ac44cf780f867e37ed2c11cc7e9855ec6df5e0/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php#L873

You can configure the default role in the wordpress admin pages.